# Fault Tolerant XML Parsing

Tags: c#-4.0

I have an XML document that I am parsing that does not follow any kind of fixed schema.  I need to parse out values by doing something like this:

```
invoiceDetail.PartNO = invoiceLine.Element(ns + "Item").Element(ns + "ItemID").Element(ns + "ID").Value;
```

In this example, invoiceLine is of XElement type.   The issue is that some nodes do not always exist and in those cases I would prefer to return null or empty instead of returning an error.  Is there any way to do this currently or should I just make a special function myself that takes a namespace and a list of element names to attempt to parse into?

Comment: If it does not follow any kind of standard, it can't be XML (which is a standard).

Comment: @Oded - Then what would you call it?  It follows the standard of having closing tags for each opening tag.  The issue is, it reuses tag names at multiple levels and repeats tags with different names at the same level.  It also is has tags that may or may not appear in different documents of the same type.

Comment: Saying it doesn't follow any standard but that it is XML is misleading. If it is well formed XML, it is well formed XML and follows that standard. If you mean that it doesn't have a fixed schema and cannot be validated against a schema, that's a different thing.

Comment: @Oded - Thank you for the clarifying point.  It doesn't have a fixed schema and can not be validated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XLINQ already does this.
`.Element()` will return `null` if there is no element with that name.

To avoid repetitive null checks, use `.Elements()` instead:

```
invoiceDetail.PartNO = (string)
    invoiceLine.Elements(ns + "Item")
               .Elements(ns + "ItemID")
               .Elements(ns + "ID")
               .SingleOrDefault();
```

Each `Elements()` call will return an `IEnumerable<XElement>`.  If there aren't any matching elements, it will return an empty sequence, and the rest of the code will still work.

`.SingleOrDefault()` will convert the final sequence to a single element or `null`.
The `(string)` cast calls a custom explicit conversion which should return `null` if the element was null.  You can similarly cast directly to basic value types.

Comment: Right but if I need to go 3 Elements deep, I have to check each result of .Element() before I go to the next one and then finally, I have to check if the last .Element() is null before getting my value or I end up with an error.

Comment: @RandomBen: Call `.Elements()` (plural) instead.  This way, you'll get an empty collection instead of `null`.

Comment: Is it an option to use invoiceLine.Descendants("ID"). It would return all "ID" elements, disregarding structure.